# Tuning Spring Boot application on Solaris 64 bit

Tags: java, spring, memory, spring-boot, solaris

On Oracle's site there's no option to download Java 8 for Solaris 32-bit, how my application will use a small heap around 128mb (Spring Boot app.), 64 bit is not the best option to save memory and speed up the application.

I read 64-bit is righter for applications that need more than 2GB, so what can I do in this case? Is there any option to set into VM about reducing memory usage?

***VM installed***

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked your application and compared 32- and 64-bit performance and memory usage?  Also, please post the output from `java -?`.

Comment: I looked via prstat command the id process and is using 300mb while on Windows 32 bit just needs 70mb(keeping in mind I dont have 32 bit on Solaris to compare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enabled by default but you might try anyway the `XX:+UseCompressedOops` option (which uses 32 bit pointers even on 64 bit JVM) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I already tried this VM option and did not make any difference about the amount of memory used. Any idea more?

Comment: Are you looking at the prstat RSS column or the SIZE one?

Comment: I am looking both, see console output: "9091 user     374M  296M sleep   59    0   0:01:00 1.0% java/9"